# async/await mixed with GetAwaiter/Result and performance

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, async-await, .net-core

My asp.net-core application (.net core 2.0) has a mixture of properly written *async / await* code with poorly written `.Wait()` `.Result` and `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` calls.

The poorly written code is deep inside 3rd party code that I don't want to touch.

My question is, how do I ensure the performance of the properly written async / await code is not negatively affected by the poorly written 3rd party code?

To give some additional context, the properly written *async* code is a bunch of socket management (handling connections, sending / receiving data), and the poorly written code is a bunch of `HttpClient.SendAsync` calls.  The two functionalities of the system are mostly separate and not-related.

The well-behaved socket code looks something similar (pseudo-ish):

```
var longRunningTask = Task.Run(async () {
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) 
    {
        var socket = await _tcpListener.AcceptSocketConnectionAsync();

        Task.Run(async () => {
            while (!someOtherToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var content = await socket.ReadAsync(); 
                var transformed = await TransformAsync(content); // almost all IO calls
                socket.WriteAsync(transformed);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Good luck. Anything that ties up to many threadpool threads will start impacting even well written async code.

Comment: That's my thinking, I am wondering if there's a recommendation for creating a secondary thread pool for the well behaved stuff.

Comment: You may have more luck doing the reverse, isolating the misbehaving components to non-threadpool threads.